# php cURL post send file not working

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send a .txt file via php cURL post but no success.

My cURL code looks like this:

```
$filedata = curl_file_create('../path/to/file.txt', 'text/plain', 'file.txt');

$array = array(
    'action' => 1,
    'file' => $filedata,
    'sec_secure' => $sec_secure,
)

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://domain_name.com/url/to/script.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = 0;

if($sec_secure == $result){
    $response = 1;
}
```

And the receiving script.php:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $contents = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    $response = $_POST['sec_secure'];
}
else{
    $response = '';
}
echo $response;
```

The problem is that is always giving me **$response = 0**.

Does anyone knows why is this happening and how to make it work as it would?

**EDIT:**

I missed this following line after $array:

```
$array = http_build_query($array);
```

Maybe that's causing the issue?

Comment: why have you set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false` ?

Comment: also `enctype=”multipart/form-data”` needs to be set for file transfers.

Comment: @RamC could you tell me how to set the enctype? And do I need to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `true`?

Comment: set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data");` and check

Comment: @RamC on `CURLOPT_HEADER` or `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true? And thanks for your answer!

Comment: Its working fine for me.

Comment: Glad to help you on this. You can now mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `enctype=”multipart/form-data”` for file transfers.

set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true

set `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to `array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data");`

Comment: The following works perfectly without headers: https://3v4l.org/E0cHv, try it... it will send the file then print_r the file contents. The OP is essentially doing the same but with 1 instead of the file contents so I dont think its headers.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it later when I get home

Comment: I just tried your code and still returns **value 0**. I don't know how to fix this...

Comment: The code is what I have written earlier. I'm starting to think that maybe I don't have to retrieve it as `$_FILES` but as `$_POST`. And also I'm not getting any errors on errorlog **[both]**... And again, thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: I've just edit my code cause I missed one line in the first place but don't know if that's relevant...

Comment: try printing `curl_error($ch);` and share your findings.

Comment: it prints nothing, i put it on console.log and it's just empty

Comment: does the `path/to/file.txt` need to be an absolute path?

Comment: Console.log?  Try to print curl_error in php.. and yeah, the path needs to be absolute

Comment: console.log on response cause this script is called by an ajax request but also try printing and no erros shown. Well, I'm gonna try with absolute path and see if it works. Thanks for your help and time, really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Header in curl.

```
$array = array(
    'action' => 1,
    'file' => $filedata,
    'sec_secure' => $sec_secure,
)
$array = json_encode($array);

$headers = array(

        'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($array)
    );

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = 0;

if($sec_secure == $result){
    $response = 1;
}
```

change the code like this.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it later when I get home!